# Mysterious Memory Leak C++

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

I am making a program that creates a 2D maze. Part of the process is populating a 2D vector with tiles that have different content in them. I seem to have created a memory leak somewhere though and hours of searching lead me to find Visual Leak Detector. I'm still having a bit of trouble finding the leak though, but I think I know the block it's in. The stack returned by VLD includes my constructor for my tiles and the function that called their creation, both of which I'll include below.

Tile constructor

```
tileL::tileL(void)
{ 
    type = 'L';
    string con = L_CON;
    for (int y=0;y<TILE_SIZE;y++)
    {
    contents.push_back(con.substr(y*TILE_SIZE,TILE_SIZE));  //VLD points to this line
    }
}
```

Going up the stack, the block that called the constructor. This block replaces a tile in the vector with another one:

```
char c;
c=contents[0][0]->getType();
if(c=='X'||c=='O'||c=='I'||c=='T')
{
    delete contents[0][0];
    contents[0][0]=new tileL(); //This is the line that calls the constructor
}
```

The tile class only has a vector of strings and a char as properties so there's just the virtual destructor. In the class that builds the vectors of tiles, the part of the destructor that deletes the vector of tiles is like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<contents.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<contents[i].size();j++)
        delete contents[i][j];
    contents[i].clear();
}
contents.clear();
```

So I'm not really seeing the memory leak anywhere. I made sure to delete the old tile before replacing it with the new one and the tiles don't have any objects in them so the default copy function should be fine right? I would really appreciate the help. If you need any more code to help me, let me know!

Comment: Please note that, typically, leak detectors do not tell you where the leak happened, but where the memory that leaked **was allocated**. Perhaps you should look instead to what happens to that memory *after.

Comment: valgrind is a bit hard to use, i think clang's ASan is much easier and source-line precise as to what actually leaked.

Comment: How does the memory leak manifest itself? Tools may be reporting false positives.

Comment: What type is `contents`?

Comment: contents is a vector<vector<Tile*>> type. The TileL class is polymorphically derived from Tile.

Comment: Does the base class Tile have the virtual desconstructor?

Comment: Note that STL containers often use pooled memory and therefore some memory remains allocated even after everything is freed. It also depends on when your memory leak detector runs (before those pools are deleted or after). It is also indicative if leak is one big block or several small blocks, if they are same size and how the amount of leaked memory scales with changing your maze size. All those are useful pointers to where the leak might have occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the offending line, I was running a .clear() method without actually 'delete'-ing the contents.

Answer (score 5):

One solution to manual memory management in modern C++ is to never use **operators new** and **delete**.
When you see them in the code - it's a sign of code smell.

Use

```
std::shared_ptr with std::make_shared
std::unique_ptr with std::make_unique
```

It will take care of deallocating stuff out of scope mostly automatically.

It will be easier to help if you provide the types of the variables you referenced in the code.

Comment: Ok I will try that out. I've never heard of those commands so I will have to do some reading on it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a counter .Just increase every time you malloc or new and decrease when u free or delete.
this will narrow your search to locate the problem.check at last the value of counter.U may also check consecutive allocation and deallocation are in order or not .